# Using NSPredicate to search within Cells in XCUITest

Tags: ios, ui-automation, xctest

Ive been using XCUITest to perform some UI Automation.
I have a collection of cells on a page, and want to return the ones that contain a label

Setting a breakpoint and typing in

```
po app.cells
```

returns

```
Output: {
      Cell 0x6080003603c0: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 184.6}, {916.5, 83.6}},  label: 'reminder same title, description, 4.38 pm'
      Cell 0x618000179380: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 268.2}, {916.5, 10.9}}
      Cell 0x608000360300: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 279.1}, {916.5, 83.6}},  label: 'reminder same title, description different, 11.37 am'
      Cell 0x618000179440: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 362.7}, {916.5, 10.9}}
      Cell 0x600000363a80: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 373.6}, {916.5, 83.6}}, label: 'reminder same title, other description, 11.03 am'
      Cell 0x608000360180: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 457.2}, {916.5, 10.9}}
      Cell 0x618000179500: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 468.0}, {916.5, 83.6}}, label: 'name A, second, 11.00 am'
      Cell 0x618000179740: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 551.7}, {916.5, 10.9}}
      Cell 0x610000177580: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 562.5}, {916.5, 83.6}}, label: 'name A, first, 11.00 am'
      Cell 0x600000363000: traits: 8589934592, {{162.9, 646.1}, {916.5, 10.9}}
      Cell 0x618000179d40: traits: 8589934592, {{409.4, 362.2}, {293.2, 27.1}}
      Cell 0x600000364800: traits: 8589934592, {{409.4, 389.3}, {293.2, 27.1}}
```

I understand that an easier way would be to have accessibility identifiers associated with the Cells that have labels, but Im unsure of how to structure a NSPredicate query in order to probe the Cells collection and only return the Cells containing a label.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you all the cells whose label is not nil

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label != nil")
let cells = XCUIApplication().cells.matching(predicate)
```